# rrddtool unknown_sec 7 and no vaules in rrd file

Tags: rrdtool

I am stuck at this from 2 days.I have used rrdtool before with success.

This one I just can't fix so far.

I have created a rrd file,

```
rrdtool create /var/www/cacti/rra/LUN372.rrd \
-s 300 \
DS:hlwanspeed:GAUGE:1200:0:120000 \
DS:sanspeed:GAUGE:1200:0:120000 \
DS:wanspeed:GAUGE:1200:0:120000 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1500
```

Then I run a cron job to update it

*/5 * * * * /root/rpa/ted.sh

But I get all the NaN values

```
last_update = 1405442886
header_size = 1208
ds[hlwanspeed].index = 0
ds[hlwanspeed].type = "GAUGE"
ds[hlwanspeed].minimal_heartbeat = 1200
ds[hlwanspeed].min = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[hlwanspeed].max = 1.2000000000e+05
ds[hlwanspeed].last_ds = "0"
ds[hlwanspeed].value = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[hlwanspeed].unknown_sec = 0
ds[sanspeed].index = 1
ds[sanspeed].type = "GAUGE"
ds[sanspeed].minimal_heartbeat = 1200
ds[sanspeed].min = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[sanspeed].max = 1.2000000000e+05
ds[sanspeed].last_ds = "0"
ds[sanspeed].value = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[sanspeed].unknown_sec = 0
ds[wanspeed].index = 2
ds[wanspeed].type = "GAUGE"
ds[wanspeed].minimal_heartbeat = 1200
ds[wanspeed].min = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[wanspeed].max = 1.2000000000e+05
ds[wanspeed].last_ds = "981976"
ds[wanspeed].value = NaN
```

Need help here.

best Regards,

W

Comment: mostly it is for the wanspeed it is coming as NaN

Comment: This is fixed now, "rrdtool create /var/www/cacti/rra/LUN372.rrd -s 300 DS:hlwanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U DS:sanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U DS:wanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1500" , this fixed it, But  why ? Not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a max speed of `ds[wanspeed].max = 1.2000000000e+05` while your last update was `ds[wanspeed].last_ds = "981976"` and since `981,976 > 120,000` rrdtool refuses the update stores `NAN`. In your 'fixed' version you just removed the upper limit by settinx `ds[wanspeed].max` to `U` which disables the input validation for high values.

Comment: Thank you Tobi, it was,  once I started really understanding it.I have beautiful portal of graphs now.

Answer (score 0):

fixed now,

`rrdtool create /var/www/cacti/rra/LUN372.rrd -s 300 DS:hlwanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U DS:sanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U DS:wanspeed:GAUGE:600:0:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1500"` ,

this fixed it,

But why ? Not sure